# Egit ssh problems

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I have been trying to get gitHub and Egit to cooperate, with no success. I installed github's software bundle and made an SSH key that way, but Egit gives me no prompt for the passphrase, and it gives me this error:

```
Cannot get remote repository refs.
Reason: ssh://git@github.com:22: passphrase for C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ssh\id_rsa
```

I have these settings in the push menu:

```
URI: ssh://git@github.com/YoungMaker/<projectName>.git
host: github.com
Repository path: /YoungMaker/<projectName>.git
protocol: SSH
port <BLANK>
User: git
password <blank>
```

I also tried the GIT_SSH environment variable, and set it to C:\Documents and Settings\User.ssh, as well as plink.exe (I don't know what that is (clearly some .exe))

After trying to push from the gitHub GUI, I got this error. Its quite strange because I have the  C:\Documents and Settings\User.ssh directory with a config file and an id_rsa key in it.

```
Pushing to git@github.com:YoungMaker/GitTester.git
error: cannot spawn C:\Documents and Settings\User\.ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but for future reference:

Make sure you did **setup a push remote**. It worked for me when I got both the *Cannot get remote repository refs*-problems ("... Passphrase for..." and "Auth fail" in the "Push..." dialog).

Provided that you already:

1. Setup your SSH keys with Github (Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2)
2. Setup your local repository (you can follow [this guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) for that)
3. Created a Github repository ([same guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Github_Tutorial))

... here's how you do it:

- Go to the **Git Repositories view** (Window > Show View > Other > Git Repositories)
- Expand your Repository and **right click Remotes** --> **"Create Remote"**
- "Remote Name": origin, "Configure push": checked --> **click "OK"**
- Click the **"Change..."** button
- **Paste your git URI** and select protocol **ssh** --> **click "Finish"**
- Now, **click "Save and Push"** and NOW you should get a password prompt --> **enter the public key passphrase** here (provided that you DID (and you should) setup a passphrase to your public key) --> **click "OK"**
- Now you should get a confirmation window saying "Pushed to *YourRepository* - origin" --> **click "OK"**
- **[Push to upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream)**, but this time **use "Configured remote repository"** as your Destination Git repository
- Go get yourself a well earned cup of coffee!

Answer (score 2):

The passphrase is needed if you created a private key protected by one, as described in "[GitHub: SSH key passphrase](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/)".
But that means you need an SSH agent to provide that passphrase for you.

If Egit doesn't prompt for one when pushing, that could mean:

- your SSH key wasn't protected by a passphrase
- your SSH key isn't somehow accessible (wrong path, or wrong protection on that path)

See also [Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github_push):

[image: Egit ssh uri]

Comment: I was following vogellas tutorial, however its outdated and there is no more option for git + ssh, only ssh and HTTPS which also gives me an error

Comment: @Young_Maker sure, the ssh address is fine. The issue is more about wether or not your SSH key is protected with a passphrase. Start first with one *without* a passphrase, easier to put in place (no need for an agent)

Comment: no, creating a new SSH key gave me a different error:
exception when executing the ls - remote command